# DropDown and ListBox don't work correctly (Next.js + TailwindCSS + HeadlessUI)

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I have issue with dropdown menu. When I click dropdown menu opens and close immediately.
I've installed TailwindCSS and HeadlessUI by docs. I've took DropDown from docs HeadlessUI.
I thought it was related with Chrome but in Safari same issue

Video link how it looks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjXTW4jxVtw

There are my configs:

Node version: v16.14.2

DropDown code:

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Listbox, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon, SelectorIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";

const people = [
  { name: "Wade Cooper" },
  { name: "Arlene Mccoy" },
  { name: "Devon Webb" },
  { name: "Tom Cook" },
  { name: "Tanya Fox" },
  { name: "Hellen Schmidt" },
];

export default function Page() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(people[0]);

  return (
    <div className="w-72 fixed top-16">
      <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
        <div className="relative mt-1">
          <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md cursor-default focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
            <span className="block truncate">{selected.name}</span>
            <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none">
              <SelectorIcon
                className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </span>
          </Listbox.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Listbox.Options className="absolute w-full py-1 mt-1 overflow-auto text-base bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg max-h-60 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
              {people.map((person, personIdx) => (
                <Listbox.Option
                  key={personIdx}
                  className={({ active }) =>
                    `cursor-default select-none relative py-2 pl-10 pr-4 ${
                      active ? "text-amber-900 bg-amber-100" : "text-gray-900"
                    }`
                  }
                  value={person}
                >
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <>
                      <span
                        className={`block truncate ${
                          selected ? "font-medium" : "font-normal"
                        }`}
                      >
                        {person.name}
                      </span>
                      {selected ? (
                        <span className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 text-amber-600">
                          <CheckIcon className="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </span>
                      ) : null}
                    </>
                  )}
                </Listbox.Option>
              ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
          </Transition>
        </div>
      </Listbox>
    </div>
  );
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.5",
    "eslint": "8.14.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Please share the code for dropdown also

Comment: @mohitmaroliya I've added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not safe to set `reactStrictMode: false`.

That issue is caused by the `Transition` component and if you remove it, it will work in your current version.

The issue is completely fixed by  `"@headlessui/react": "^1.6.0"` as of now.

Comment: great! Thank you! But why is installing 1.5.0 by default?

Comment: when u install a package it installs the latest by default. so when you installed this package it was 1.5.0. 1.6.0 is published 6 days ago

Answer (score 0):

The [problem](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/681) is with Transition and Strict Mode. There are two ways to solve it.

**Solution 1**

Build the project and then start.

```
next build
```

```
next start
```

**Solution 2**

The best solution. Disable strict mode in the `next.config.js`.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```